# how to save the result of webs craping in the out put file text with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

the code below retrieve all the data from the url below. But I want to save the results in the output file text. like (info.text), Would you mind help me.

url: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/exp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-02-01&r9=2022-02-01

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/exp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-02-01&r9=2022-02-01"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\Python310\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
table = driver.find_element_by_id('report_table')
body = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
cells = body.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')

for cell in cells:
    print(cell.text)

# run the loop 26 times
for i in range(26):
    
    # your code
    table = driver.find_element_by_id('report_table')
    body = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
    cells = body.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for cell in cells:
        print(cell.text)
        
    # click on the Next button    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_results_next"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the results from a variable (seems like `cell.text` in your example), we just need to open a file and write that data to the file.

```
with open("info.txt", “w”, encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
   f.write(cell.txt)
```

This is making an assumption that `cell.text` is a string, by the way

Comment: your right cell.text is correct and my string. may you put it between the code. I put it after ( for cell in cells:) code but it doesn't work.  I am new in this area I don't know where should I put it.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific when you say it didn’t work? Is it that no .txt file that got created? Or was there an error? Either way, I believe you put that code snippet in the correct location, however you will run into an issue where the file will overwrite itself every time, so you will only have 1 .txt file. One solution would be to clump all of your scraped data together and save it off as one file, in which case you will write to the file only once outside the for loop. Another solution is to change the file name in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, you can read further about file handling [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
import time


options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("w3c", True)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

f = open("datafile.txt", "a")

url = "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/exp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-02-01&r9=2022-02-01"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

driver.get(url)
table = driver.find_element_by_id('report_table')
body = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
cells = body.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')

for cell in cells:
    #print(cell.text)
    f.write(cell.text)

# run the loop 26 times
for i in range(26):
    
    # your code
    table = driver.find_element_by_id('report_table')
    body = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
    cells = body.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for cell in cells:
        #print(cell.text)
        f.write(cell.text)
        
    # click on the Next button    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_results_next"]').click()
f.close()
```

Comment: Dear Pahllavi I run it but it didn't work. I don't know why?? have you test it?

Comment: yes i shared after making it work. it will create a text file in the folder of execution with the name datafile.txt

Comment: please note that file is created in the "a"  append format.